# Adjusting a Child ViewController inside another viewController

Tags: ios

I am trying out an application using a child ViewController inside another viewController.
I have a VC and I am instantiating another VC with its own xib inside the outer VC.

I am adding it as a child using the new iOS 5 method addChildViewController and also I have added its view as a subView.

But how do I control its position and size inside the parent view controller ?

should I modify the frame of the child controller's view ?
or I have to adjust the freeform view in the xib itself ?

Also in my current implementation, the child view starts behind the status bar of the parent viewcontroller's view.
Any idea on how to systematically implemement something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define SUBVIEWS_FRAME CGRectMake(0,20,100,100) // whatever frame you need
- (void)addChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childController{

    [childController.view setFrame:SUBVIEWS_FRAME];
    [super addChildViewController:childController];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply just add a view in parentViewController @`synthesize` that view like `childView`. now add your `childViewController` as a subView in `childView` of `parentViewController`. it will simple to adjust using `parentViewController` View on nib file. If you have a large `childViewController` then please use `UIScrollView` instad of `UIView`